# Read textfile with a mix of floats, integers and strings in the same column

Tags: matlab, text-files, ascii

Loading a well formatted and delimited text file in Matlab is relatively simple, but I struggle with a text file that I have to read in. Sadly I can not change the structure of the source file, so I have to deal with what I have.

The basic file structure is:

```
123 180 (two integers, white space delimited)
1.5674e-8
.
.
(floating point numbers in column 1, column 2 empty)
.
.
100 4501 (another two integers)
5.3456e-4 (followed by even more floating point numbers)
.
. 
.
.
45 String (A integer in column 1, string in column 2)
.
.
.
```

A simple

```
[data1,data2]=textread('filename.txt','%f %s', ...
                    'emptyvalue', NaN)
```

Does not work.
How can I properly filter the input data? All examples I found online and in the Matlab help so far deal with well structured data, so I am a bit lost at where to start.

As I have to read a whole bunch of those files >100 I rather not iterate trough every single line in every file. I hope there is a much faster approach.

EDIT: 
I made a sample file available here: [test.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_xGJzbcDtXKS1QwSm13S29FN00/view?usp=sharing) (google drive)

Comment: Can you give a complete example of such a file (i.e. the actual text in the file, not your description of what is there)? Perhaps cutting down the total number of rows to a manageable number (say < 20). Also, do the whitespace-delimited integers tell you anything useful about the file, for example do they correspond to the number of rows following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at the text file you supplied and tried to draw a few general conclusions -

1. When there are two integers on a line, the second integer corresponds to the number of rows following.
2. You always have (two integers (A, B) followed by "B" floats), repeated twice.
3. After that you have some free-form text (or at least, I couldn't deduce anything useful about the format after that).

This is a messy format so I doubt there are going to be any nice solutions. Some useful general principles are:

- Use `fgetl` when you need to read a single line (it reads up to the next newline character)
- Use `textscan` when it's possible to read multiple lines at once - it is much faster than reading a line at a time. It has many options for how to parse, which it is worth getting to know (I recommend typing `doc textscan` and reading the entire thing).
- If in doubt, just read the lines in as strings and then analyse them in MATLAB.

With that in mine, here is a simple parser for your files. It will probably need some modifications as you are able to infer more about the structure of the files, but it is reasonably fast on the ~700 line test file you gave.

I've just given the variables dummy names like "a", "b", "floats" etc. You should change them to something more specific to your needs.

```
function output = readTestFile(filename)

    fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

    % Read the first line
    line = '';
    while isempty(line)
        line = fgetl(fid);
    end
    nums = textscan(line, '%d %d', 'CollectOutput', 1);

    a = nums{1}(1);
    b = nums{1}(2);

    % Read 'b' of the next lines:
    contents = textscan(fid, '%f', b);
    floats1 = contents{1};

    % Read the next line:
    line = '';
    while isempty(line)
        line = fgetl(fid);
    end
    nums = textscan(line, '%d %d', 'CollectOutput', 1);

    c = nums{1}(1);
    d = nums{1}(2);

    % Read 'd' of the next lines:
    contents = textscan(fid, '%f', d);
    floats2 = contents{1};

    % Read the rest:
    rest = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');

    output.a = a;
    output.b = b;
    output.c = c;
    output.d = d;
    output.floats1 = floats1;
    output.floats2 = floats2;
    output.rest = rest{1};

end
```

Comment: Well spotted. Your solution works on all test files I have tried so far. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the file line by line using the lower-level functions, then parse each line manually.

You open the file handle like in C

```
fid = fopen(filename);
```

Then you can read a line using `fgetl`

```
line = fgetl(fid);
```

String tokenize it on spaces is probably the best first pass, storing each piece in a cell array (because a matrix doesn't support ragged arrays)

```
colnum = 1;
while ~isempty(rem)
    [token, rem] = strtok(rem, ' ');
    entries{linenum, colnum} = token;
    colnum = colnum + 1;
end
```

then you can wrap all of that inside another while loop to iterate over the lines

```
linenum = 1;
while ~feof(fid)
    % getl, strtok, index bookkeeping as above
end
```

It's up to you whether it's best to parse the file as you read it or read it into a cell array first and then go over it afterwards.

Your cell entries are all going to be strings (char arrays), so you will need to use `str2num` to convert them to numbers. It does a good job of working out the format so that might be all you need.